# Python test coverage for class' __str__

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm, coverage.py

I have a very basic questing regarding Python coverage tests using PyCharm IDE. In my Django models, all the `__str__` methods are not covered in my tests.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What would be the appropriate way to test these?

This doesn't work, the test runs but the `__str__` method is still not seen as covered.

```py
class TestCategory(TestCase):

    def test_category(self):
        category = Category.objects.create(name='Test Category')
        self.assertEqual(category.__str__(), 'Test Category')
```

Comment: You need to add the information how exactly the code does not work.

Comment: What happens if you do `self.assertEqual(category, 'Test Category')`

Comment: The code does work. The issue is that running coverage.py it says that `__str__` is not coverd

Comment: What coverage tool do you use?

Comment: PyCharm (Professional). I'm sure I am doing something wrong, because I'm new to this.

Comment: You do not seem to be doing anything wrong. Let me check if I can reproduce.

Comment: Is  _anything_ showing up as covered? Or is it just this one test?

Comment: Most of the code is covered, just the __str__ methods not. This issue only happens in PyCharm it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__str__()` method is called whenever you call  `str()` on an object.

**You should try it using `str()` method on the instance object.**

```
class TestCategory(TestCase):

    def test_category(self):
        category = Category.objects.create(name='Test Category')
        self.assertEqual(str(category), 'Test Category')
```

Comment: @Hoenie, Please have a look and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Hoenie, I have checked it and it's working. Can you tell me the error you getting after you do the suggested change.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. My issue is that coverage.py still tells me that it is uncovered.

Comment: Does your test case pass?

Comment: Yes it does pass

Comment: Then that does mean that your coverage.py tool has some problem. You can try checking the coverage.py configs or should try with different coverage tool.

Comment: You are right Astik. This issue only happens in PyCharm it seems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hoenie, I am glad that it did help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Astik Anand has already provided a nice answer explaining how to *technically* force an execution of the `__str__()` method.  I would, however, like to answer your question by interpreting it a bit differently - taking also the new information from the comments into account that the coverage tool seems to have an issue:

"How should I test the `__str__()` method although I know that my coverage tool is buggy and no matter what I have tried so far my tests will not get `__str__()` marked as covered by the tool?".

Take a step back.  Forget about coverage.  Coverage is not your goal.  Your goal is to find all those bugs that might be found in `__str__()`.  So, test `__str__()` as thoroughly as needed to reach this goal.  This is how to test `__str__()` (mentally, not technically).

Sorry if you think that this was clear anyway - you would not believe what people do in the face of buggy coverage tools to reach their coverage goals...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn’t expect such an simple case to be an issue for the coverage tool, so that’s why I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved the problem using the following information from

https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/coverage.html

1. `pip install django-nose`
2. in `settings.py`

   add `django_nose` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

   also, at the bottom of the file, add:

   ```
   TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
   NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=app_1,app_2',
    '--cover-html' ]
   ```

I ran coverage HTML from the command line, and the report showed that the `__str__` method from my model was covered.